# Would mold eventually just die by itself if its environment was made uninhabitable?

Tags: mold

I decided to move my noisy server farm into my basement. I enhanced the ventilation somewhat with 500CFM intake/exhaust fans and in combination with the heat coming off the farm, the room is now a cozy ~30C with around 25% humidity.

Anyways, the basement also has a mold problem. It has exposed limestone walls with mortar between the stones and half of its 2 walls are pretty much covered with the mold (mostly the mortar, stones not so much).

Its been that way since I moved into the house and I've considered getting rid of the mold but there hasn't been any real need for it. Several days after I moved in the servers though, I noticed that the moldy/mildewy smell was pretty much gone.

So just out of curiosity, if I keep this up, would the mold just die by itself in a dry and toasty room? How can I tell when its dead? Would it change color? Its black/brownish right now. I had a dream that it would turn white and I could just vacuum it up like dust, I have weird dreams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the right (or wrong, depending on your point of view) environment, mold will die.

So to answer your question, the mold will die with a lack of moisture. However, there is a catch. The spores (seeds) can be preserved, apparently for more years than you and I will be alive.

Molds can come in all kinds of colors, so there is no one answer to the color question.

Also, as this is a basement, by the very nature of basements, it is unlikely you will prevent all moisture from existing or returning in that environment. Basements are typically moist, but your server farm will certainly stifle the molds ability to grow.

Nonetheless, the mold, whatever kind(s) it is, can still be a health hazard, and you are living in a home that probably pulls some air from the basement via wiring holes, furnace, etc. -- With the addition of a server farm there, you now have a continuous circulation of air.

Obviously it is up to you what you do but disturbing mold and making it airborne is more dangerous than leaving it be. Mold remediation can be costly, especially if it turns out its not a breed that poses a health hazard.

Since any mold can pose health hazards, even if just allergy based, perhaps consider getting it cleaned by a pro and take peace of mind that the server farm will stop its growth.